# Connect to AWS RDS database via psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, psycopg2, aws-security-group

I am trying to connect to my RDS database from my computer with a python script using psycopg2.
python code:

```
import psycopg2
from db_credentials import *
import logging

def get_psql_conn():
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=DB_NAME, user=DB_USER, password=DB_PASS, host=DB_HOST)
    logging.info("connected to DB!")
    return conn
```

I get the following error:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
        Is the server running on host ********* and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

My security groups assigned to the RDS database:

 SG 1:
[image]

[image]

SG 2:
[image]

[image]

Now i tried to make a security group which allows my computer IP to access the DB.

SG 3:
[image]

[image]

I can connect to the DB from my ec2 instances, running the same python script as above. This seemingly has to do with the 2nd security group, as when i remove it, i can no longer connect from my ec2 instances either. It then throws the same error i get when trying to connect from my computer.

I have little understanding of RDS or security groups, i just followed internet tutorials, but seemingly couldnt make much sense out of it.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Is the Amazon RDS instance in a public subnet, or a private subnet? What is the value of the `Publicly Accessible` setting? See also: [Troubleshoot connectivity to an Amazon RDS instance using the public or private subnet of a VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connectivity-instance-subnet-vpc/)

Comment: It wasnt public until today. I ended up making it public and everything works fine now, so thanks for your reply :) I suppose this is still fine from a security perspective given i m just a solo dev with not so intresting data on my db and its still behind a password.

Comment: The Public setting gives it a public IP address that is reachable from the Internet. Just keep your Security Group locked-down (as you have done) and you'll be safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When accessing an Amazon RDS database from the Internet, the database needs to be configured for `Publicly Accessible = Yes`.

This will assign a Public IP address to the database instance. The DNS Name of the instance will also resolve to the public IP address.

For good security on publicly-accessible databases, ensure that the Security Group only permits access from your personal IP address.